# Eliminate equal objects and increment the innermost property by 1, based on the number of equal objects

Tags: javascript

I have the following code that eliminates equal objects in an array, and also increment the innermost property to the number of equal objects:

```js
let SUPER = [{
    "NAME1": {
      "12": {
        "10": 1
      }
    }
  }, {
    "NAME1": {
      "12": {
        "10": 1
      }
    }
  }, {
    "NAME1": {
      "12": {
        "10": 1
      }
    }
  }, {
    "NAME1": {
      "12": {
        "10": 1
      }
    }
  }, {
    "NAME1": {
      "12": {
        "11": 1
      }
    }
  }],
  FINAL = [];

for (let _super of SUPER) {
  _super = JSON.stringify(_super);
  let ii = 1,
    ll = SUPER.length,
    number = 1;

  for (ii; ii < ll; ii++) {
    let current = JSON.stringify(SUPER[ii]);
    if (_super === current) {
      SUPER.splice(ii, 1);
      ii--;
      number++;
    }
  }

  if (number) {
    FINAL.push(function clone(destination, source) {
      destination = destination || {};
      for (var prop in source) {
        typeof source[prop] === 'object' && source[prop] !== null && source[prop] ? destination[prop] = clone({}, source[prop]) : destination[prop] = number;
      }
      return destination;
    }({}, JSON.parse(_super)));
  }
}

document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(FINAL, null, 4);
```

And is almost working, if wasn't for the wrong result when there are two objects or more. The result should be:

```
[{
    "NAME1": {
      "12": {
        "10": 4
      }
    }
  }, {
    "NAME1": {
      "12": {
        "11": 1
      }
    }
  }]
```

Not:

```
[{
    "NAME1": {
      "12": {
        "10": 4
      }
    }
  }, {
    "NAME1": {
      "12": {
        "11": 2
      }
    }
  }]
```

Any ideas why?

The data given is example data. I don't know the actual properties of all the objects.

Comment: Is your first for loop "for (let _super of SUPER)" intended to act as a forEach loop? It only iterates twice and I don't think the code ends up doing what you want it to do.

Comment: You're starting `number` at `1` and then incrementing it when you find a match from within the same set, so why shouldn't it be `2`? The inner loop is clearly going to encounter the same object from the outer.

Comment: yes, the intention of the for of is a forEach.

Comment: If your logic was correct, the first object would be 5 @squint

Comment: Your `ii` starts at `1`, so you're never removing index `0`, so the second object finds itself at index `1` and so it encounters itself in the inner loop.

Comment: With ii = 0 or ii = 1, both results will be wrong. If i edit can u take a look? @squint.

Comment: If you're going to keep the first item of each object in the array, then you'll need to start `ii` at an increased value every time. So at the top, create `var j = 0;` and then initialize `ii` with `var ii = (j+=1)`, and I think that should take care of it.

Comment: ...I should note that I don't know what side effects there will be on the outer `for-of` loop by mutating the array during iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problems:

- it was adding 1 in all iterations except for the first one
- using "for (let _super of SUPER) {" when SUPER was losing items

I've tested with more 'unique' elements. If you run the code below you'll see the correct result.

```js
var SUPER = [
    { "NAME1": { "12": { "21": 1 } } }, 
 { "NAME1": { "12": { "21": 1 } } }, 
 { "NAME1": { "12": { "10": 1 } } }, 
 { "NAME1": { "12": { "10": 1 } } }, 
 { "NAME1": { "12": { "10": 1 } } }, 
 { "NAME1": { "12": { "10": 1 } } }, 
 { "NAME1": { "12": { "10": 1 } } },
 { "NAME1": { "12": { "12": 1 } } }, 
 { "NAME1": { "12": { "11": 1 } } }, 
 { "NAME1": { "12": { "11": 1 } } }],
 FINAL = [];

var firstPass = true;

for (var i = 0; i < SUPER.length; i++) {
  _super = JSON.stringify(SUPER[i]);
  let ii = 1,
    ll = SUPER.length,
    number = 1;

  for (ii; ii < ll; ii++) {
    let current = JSON.stringify(SUPER[ii]);
    if (_super === current) {
      SUPER.splice(ii, 1);
      ii--;
      number++;
    }
  }

  if (number) {
    FINAL.push(function clone(destination, source) {
      destination = destination || {};
      for (var prop in source) {
        typeof source[prop] === 'object' && source[prop] !== null && source[prop] ? destination[prop] = clone({}, source[prop]) : (firstPass) ? destination[prop] = number : destination[prop] = number -1;
      }
      firstPass = false;
      return destination;
    }({}, JSON.parse(_super)));
  }
 
  if (SUPER.length > 0 && SUPER.length <= i) {
     i = 0;
  }
}

document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(FINAL, null, 4);
```

Output:

```
[ { "NAME1": { "12": { "21": 2 } } }, { "NAME1": { "12": { "10": 5 } } }, { "NAME1": { "12": { "11": 2 } } }, { "NAME1": { "12": { "12": 1 } } } ]
```

What's new? (comparing with your code)

- **firstPass** declaration as true
- decrement 1 from number at "typeof source[prop] === 'object' && source[prop] !== null && source[prop] ? destination[prop] = clone({}, source[prop]) : **(firstPass) ? destination[prop] = number : destination[prop] = number -1;**"
- set **firstPass** to false
- 'for' using index i instead of letting JS iterate through SUPER (since we remove elements from SUPER) by its own
- reset 'i' to zero if i > SUPER.length

note: you can fix it in many different ways, that's just one of them ;)

ps: despite the code is working, I still don't know the root cause of your problem with "number" =/ so, I consider "(firstPass) ? destination[prop] = number : destination[prop] = number - 1" being a workaround rather than the real fix.

Comment: Isn't work properly, check : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wGVXBd?editors=0010 i add a item in the SUPER. The problem is related with the ii--; i think

Comment: well, I checked it by copying it and pasting it in chrome inspector (F12) in console. I'll double check it later then... meanwhile... could you do the same check in chrome console?

Comment: I checked, your code is working, but when i add a item in the SUPER, will mess the count, didn't u saw?

Comment: @D_REIS you right, it was leaving the for block before verifying all elements from SUPER because SUPER lost items. I've tested with more items in SUPER and it is working now... hope this helps

Comment: Can u provide a functional example? For me isn't @awdk.

Comment: sure, I'll modify my post in a moment

Comment: @D_REIS, can you see it now ? :)

Comment: Perfect, is working now and is faster then nina's answer, and i also prefer this type of code, imperative way, functional is to mess-up.

Answer (score 1):

You could generate all keys first, have a lookup if an element is inserted with that path and if not create an entry. After that, build the path in the object and at last add the value to most inner object.

```js
let SUPER5 = [{ "NAME1": { "12": { "10": 1 } } }, { "NAME1": { "12": { "10": 1 } } }, { "NAME1": { "12": { "10": 1 } } }, { "NAME1": { "12": { "10": 1 } } }, { "NAME1": { "12": { "11": 1 } } }],
    SUPER10 = [{ "NAME1": { "12": { "21": 1 } } }, { "NAME1": { "12": { "21": 1 } } }, { "NAME1": { "12": { "10": 1 } } }, { "NAME1": { "12": { "10": 1 } } }, { "NAME1": { "12": { "10": 1 } } }, { "NAME1": { "12": { "10": 1 } } }, { "NAME1": { "12": { "10": 1 } } }, { "NAME1": { "12": { "12": 1 } } }, { "NAME1": { "12": { "11": 1 } } }, { "NAME1": { "12": { "11": 1 } } }],
    getGrouped = data => {
        var r = [],
            getKey = o => Object.keys(o)[0];
        data.forEach(function (a) {
            var o = a,
                t = {},
                k = getKey(a),
                keys = [k],
                jointKey;

            while (typeof o[k] === 'object') {
                o = o[k];
                k = getKey(o);
                keys.push(k);
            }
            jointKey = keys.join('|');
            if (!this[jointKey]) {
                this[jointKey] = t;
                r.push(t);
            }
            keys.pop();
            t = keys.reduce((r, a) => r[a] = r[a] || {}, this[jointKey]);
            t[k] = (t[k] || 0) + o[k];
        }, Object.create(null));
        return r;
    };

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(getGrouped(SUPER5), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(getGrouped(SUPER10), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Perfect, i was seeking for this kind of answer for days. thank you nina!!

Comment: Nina, if u don't mine, what is var key = o => Object.keys(object)[0],??

Comment: @D_REIS, if you look my latest code you'll see that's working. Also, I ran Nina's code with my new SUPER with 10 elements and the output of Nina's seems to be wrong. D_REIS can you double check that ? Nina's code have the second problem listed in my post regarding the "for"

Comment: @D_REIS, its an arrow function, which returns the first key of an object.

Comment: @NinaScholz before I commented above I did double checked locally and somehow it was not right (I mean that the output was not the expected one with 10 elements). However before I add this comment I triple checked it locally and, for my surprise, it is working! That's why I +1ed it.